# Get the total number of rows for the selected month WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for a way to count the number of days based on the selected month from a datepicker.

The date and the id field in my model are defined as:  `public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }` 
 `public int ID { get; set; }`

```
 private DateTime _mDate = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime MDate
    {

        get { return _mDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _mDate)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (_selectedTabIndex == 0)
            {
                _mDate = value;
            }

            else
            {
                _mDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MDate");
                SetDaysCompleted();
            }

        }

    }


private void SetDaysCompleted()
        {
         int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out int month);
         DaysCompleted = Convert.ToDecimal(db.MyTable
.Where(a => (a.Date < MDate) && (int.TryParse(a.Date.ToString("MM"), out int smonth) == month))
.Select(a => a.ID).Count());
         }
```

I hoped something like this would work but I get a "*No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"* error. Can someone please suggest how should I rewrite the query or if there's a better way to get the row count from the beginning of the selected month? Thank you.

Comment: `int.TryParse(a.Date.ToString("MM"), out int smonth) == month` - this will not work as `int.TryParse` returns boolean (success or not). And you want to compare the result (`smonth`) with `month`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Andrew. I have tried your solution and this is what I get: 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but I think the issue lies here:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }  
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Try converting the `Nullable<System.DateTime> Date` to `System.DateTime Date` first in order to be able to use `.ToString("MM")` on it.

Another potential issue in your code could be : `Where(a=>(a.Date < MDate)`. Again, if I'm understanding correctly `a.Date` is of type `DateTime?` and cannot be compared to `DateTime MDate`

Comment: You can do: `a.Date.HasValue && int.Parse(a.Date.Value.ToString("MM") == month)`

Comment: Hello Farzan, Thank you for your prompt response. I have converted it to not nullable. Now I get the following error:  "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer". You are correct, a.Date is Datetime? and the comparison works with DateTime MDate. The second part doesn't work. I've tried  Convert.ToDecimal(db.MyTable.Where(a => (a.Date < MDate) && (a.Date.Month = month)).Select(a => a.ID).Count()); but I get the following error: Property or indexer 'DateTime.Month' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @iCosmin that's great, in your code `a.Data.Month = month` is an assignment, try `a.Data.Month == month`

Comment: Farzan, you are great!!! Thank you so much, that solved my problem. Have a nice evening!

Comment: glad I could help!